# How to display Multiple Highchart in single page

Tags: jquery, jsp, highcharts

I am trying to divide the `jsp` page into four equal section to to display four `highchart`. I know little bit about `highchart` but dont how to divide single jsp page into four equal part. I am able to display single chart on jsp but really dont know how to display four chart in single `jsp`.

**My jsp page would look like that**
[image]

Comment: How do you display one chart? To the same 4x and later use some CSS to position charts as you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out how to do that:

1. To divide the page the best option is to use the `bootstrap css` its
   easy and gives you great flexibility.
2. To display the chart I have used `High-chart` its a open source and
   good.

Now how do we do that.
First I have divide the page using  tag with predefined bootstrap css classes `col-md-6`. it means it divide the hole screen in two column. if you do not know about this learn `bootstrap css grid system` Link  [Bootstrap css grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

**This is how I am dividing the screen two column two row with `<div>` tag**

***At every `<div id="#">` I would display the high chart.***

```html
<div class="container">
            <h1 align="center"><a href ="#">Different charts in one page</a></h1>
            <!--First chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">      
                        <div id="pie" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>   
                            
                    </div>
                <!--Second chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="bar" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--Third chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="Stacked" style="min-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--Fourth chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="line" style="min-width: 600px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--End of charts-->
        </div><!--for container div-->
```

**Here is full code**

Make sure you include the `HighChart` `js`

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>final</title>
        <!--Bootstrap source start-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--Bootstrap source end-->
        
        <!--highchart source start-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Global Soft\Desktop\HighChart\js\highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
        
        
        <style type="text/css">
            ${demo.css}
        </style>
        
        <!--Pie Chart starts here-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
            var pieChart;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                pieChart=new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'pie',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                            
                    title: {
                        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
                    },
                    
                    subtitle:{
                        text: ' Pie Chart'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    },
                    
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Browser share',
                        data: [
                            ['Firefox',   45.0],
                            ['IE',       26.8],
                            {
                                name: 'Chrome',
                                y: 12.8,
                                sliced: true,
                                selected: true
                            },
                            ['Safari',    8.5],
                            ['Opera',     6.2],
                            ['Others',   0.7]
                        ]
                    }]
                
                    
            });
            
        }); 
        <!--Pie chart ends here-->
        
        
        <!--bar stacked chart start here-->
        $('#Stacked').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
        <!--bar stacked chart end here  -->
        
        <!--bar chart start here-->
    $('#bar').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
    
        <!--bar chart start here-->
        
        <!--Line chart start here-->
        $('#line').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
    
    <!--Line chart ends here-->
        
        

});<!--This is for the main function-->






    </script>
                        

        <!--Charts end here-->

        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <h1 align="center"><a href ="#">Different charts in one page</a></h1>
            <!--First chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">      
                        <div id="pie" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>   
                            
                    </div>
                <!--Second chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="bar" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--Third chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="Stacked" style="min-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--Fourth chart-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="line" style="min-width: 600px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--End of charts-->
        </div><!--for container div-->
    </body>
</html>
```

***OutPut***

[image]